# Detecting a face by using play-services-vision and extract that information

Tags: android, face-detection

I am working on a Android project in which I have to detect faces and then show the age probability of all detected images. I am using the **play-services-vision** API for this purpose, and I have successfully detected the faces.

By using a Face instance of this API I can only detect the smiling probability and left or right eye open probability.

Is it possible by using this API I can estimate the age and if it is then how?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Vision [FaceAnnotation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#FaceAnnotation) does not support `Age & Gender` detection;

but other providers can ... see this [comparison chart](https://www.kairos.com/blog/face-recognition-kairos-vs-microsoft-vs-google-vs-amazon-vs-opencv).

Comment: Thanks Martin, But can you please tell me other possible solutions for this purpose in android?

Comment: @KhurramAnsar just see the comparison chart ...an API is not platform specific, at all.